# notification sound when checking airtime balance

Tags: 8.1

Everytime I check the balance on my phone or do cellphone banking there's an alert. How do I put this on silence or off without turning the ringer off?

Comment: What app are you using for this? What kind of alert is it? In general, you should be able to disable alerts for any app from Settings -> notifications+actions.